# product of string

Tags: erlang

I need a function which return the product of numbers in the string:

```
SomeFunc("1234") -> 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 = 24
```

Here is my code:

```
lists:foldr(fun(X, Y) -> X * Y end, 1, "1234").
```

But I get 6497400.

Why and how can I fix the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is multiplying the ascii codes of the characters, i.e. 49*50*51*52. In order to get your desired result, use

```
lists:foldr(fun(X, Y) -> (X-$0)*Y end, 1, "1234")
```

where `$0` is the ASCII code for the character '0'.

Comment: Hmmm.... I get -1560. I think it is because of the second argument of foldr - '1'.

Comment: lists:foldr(fun(X, Y) -> (X-$0)*Y end, 1, "1234") - here is right version, but it looks a little magic.  May be there is any other way to convert a string to list of integers?

Comment: Of course you're right. I fixed it. The second argument already contains the product up to the current position, which is apparently *not* an ASCII code :)

Comment: Why "magic"? ;) "1234" is the same as a list `[49,50,51,52]`. in order to convert it ot a list `[1,2,3,4]` you could use `lists:map(fun(X) -> (X-48) end, "1234")`. And `$0` is the ASCII code for '0', i.e. 48. So the entire multiplication could also be written as `lists:foldr(fun(X, Y) -> X*Y end, 1, lists:map(fun(Z) -> (Z-$0), "1234"))`, although this would require two traversals of the list.

Comment: A bit less magical but still ugly would be `lists:foldr(fun(X, Y) -> list_to_integer([X])*Y end, 1, "1234")` since the X needs to be put back into a list in order to be converted to int.